# Java: Using Object as a super class (why a given statement is not working and how to fix it?)

Tags: java, class, object, super

Java question: Can someone please tell me why the statement obj.f1(); below does not work 
and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
class X{
     void f1() {
       System.out.println("XXX") ;
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    void f1(){
        System.out.println("YYY");
    }
}    



public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object obj =  new Y();
        obj.f1();  // why this does not work?

    }

}
```

Comment: If I am correct in assuming this is Java, please add the java tag via the edit button under your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is java, as you have not marked it as such:

You seem to be under the impression that java is dynamically type-checked, while in reality it is statically. This means that since you have declared `obj` as type `Object`, the compiler is rejecting your code because `Object` has no method `f1()`.

The compiler doesn't care what you initialize it to, a local/field's delared type (the one in front) determines what can be called on it.

To fix this, you'll need to declare `obj` as a `Y`, like so: `Y obj = new Y();`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @Mariav No problem. If my solution helped, I'd appreciate if you could accept it by clicking the checkmark to it's left. :)